# DocuSign: Getting envelope info

Tags: docusignapi

I've uploaded a test file to docusign where I get a document id as a response: `08eebff6-0cbc-4831-b317-c73ba3e2f61d`

When I try to read with:

`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes?from_date=2010-01-01`

I get an empty envelope response:

```
{
    "resultSetSize": "0",
    "totalSetSize": "0",
    "nextUri": "",
    "previousUri": "",
    "envelopes": []
}
```

When I try to read it with:
`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes/08eebff6-0cbc-4831-b317-c73ba3e2f61d/documents`

I get a proper response:

```
{
    "envelopeId": "08eebff6-0cbc-4831-b317-c73ba3e2f61d"
}
```

For my understanding, I also expect some result in the first response such as the envelope Id in the example above should be in the envelopes array in the first response. Am I correct or am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. Please "check" the answer that best solves your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first step, I will assume that you meant to say that you created an *envelope* not a *document.* Yes?

Did you `send` the envelope or `create` it? (a draft)

If you sent the envelope properly, then I agree that it should have shown up in your Envelopes: listStatusChanges query. See if your envelope shows in the web browser at demo.docusign.net

You can also try the [listStatusChanges method via the API Explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=Envelopes&operations=listStatusChanges).

You can also help improve your question by showing the response from your initial Envelopes: create call.

**Update:** I just created a *draft* envelope and it did not show up in the listStatusChanges results. A newly created *sent* envelope was listed. I'm not sure if this is by design or not, I will enquire with the DocuSign engineering group.

Comment: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<accId>/envelopes
this is the request I am sending with the file itself is added to request body as a binary stream.

{  "envelopeId": "648412b9-ab8a-4fee-8f6f-7d8884148776",  "uri": "/envelopes/648412b9-ab8a-4fee-8f6f-7d8884148776",  "statusDateTime": "2016-07-26T13:33:21.6730000Z",  "status": "created"}
This is the response that I am getting. I expect to see the envelope that I created in the response list at my first request.

Comment: @hchaznedaroglu, yup, it's a puzzle. If you send an envelope via the web browser, does it show when you do the envelopes query?  Maybe there's an issue that you're using a date before your account was created. Try a from_date of yesterday instead of 2010.

Comment: We know the calls work since you can try them from the api explorer, so you'll need to do stepwise debugging to find the problem.

Comment: I tried giving yesterday's date as "from_date" after I sent another envelope creation request. Response is same though. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Send your envelope and check that it is shown in the web browser. 2. Try the API call via the API Explorer, apiexplorer.docusign.com

Comment: Merhaba :) try URL encoding your date.  See the answer I just posted.  Cheers

Comment: After I created the envelope through api explorer, I became able to see the envelopeId in status changes. I will go ahead and check what was wrong in my API request then. Thanks for the help :) Tesekkurler

Answer (score 0):

Try URL encoding your `from_date`, for instance try something like this:

```
?from_date=2010%2F01%2F01
```